# Parsing HTML with BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse HTML with Python using BeautifulSoup, but I can't manage to get what I need.

This is a little module of a personal app I want to do, and it consists in a web login part with credentials, and once the script is logged in the web, I need to parse some information in order to manage it and process it.

The HTML code after getting logged is:

```
<div class="widget_title clearfix">

        <h2>Account Balance</h2>

    </div>

    <div class="widget_body">

        <div class="widget_content">

            <table class="simple">

                <tr>

                    <td><a href="#" id="west1" title="Total earned daily">Daily Earnings</a></td>

                    <td style="text-align: right; width: 125px; color: #119911; font-weight: bold;">

                        150                         

                    </td>

                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td><a href="#" id="west2" title="Total weekly earnings">Weekly Earnings</a></td>

                    <td style="text-align: right; border-bottom: 1px solid #000; color: #119911; font-weight: bold;">

                        500                     </td>

                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td><a href="#" id="west3" title="Total Monthly earnings">Monthly Earnings</a></td>

                    <td style="text-align: right; color: #119911; font-weight: bold;">

                        1500                        </td>

                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td><a href="#" id="west4" title="Total expenses">Total expended</a></td>

                    <td style="text-align: right; border-bottom: 1px solid #000; color: #880000; font-weight: bold;">

                        430                     </td>

                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td><a href="#" id="west5" title="Total available">Account Balance</a></td>

                    <td style="text-align: right; border-bottom: 3px double #000; color: #119911; font-weight: bold;">

                        840                     </td>

                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td></td>

                    <td style="padding: 5px;">

                        <center>

                            <form id="request_bill" method="POST" action="index.php?page=dashboard">

                                <input type="hidden" name="secret_token" value="" />

                                <input type="hidden" name="request_payout" value="1" />

                                <input type="submit" class="btn blue large" value="Request Payout" />

                            </form>

                        </center>

                    </td>

                </tr>

            </table>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

As you can see, it's not a very well-formatted HTML, but I'd need to extract the elements and their values, I mean, for example: "Daily earnings" and "150" | "Weekly earnings" and "500"...

I think that the "id" attribute may help, but when I try to parse it, it crashes.

The Python code I'm working with is:

```
def parseo(archivohtml):
    html = archivohtml
    parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(html)
    par = parsed_html.find('td', attrs={'id':'west1'}).string
    print par
```

Where archivohtml is the saved html file after logging in the web

When I run the script, I only get errors.

I've also tried doing this:

```
def parseo(archivohtml):
    soup = BeautifulSoup()
    html = archivohtml
    parsed_html = soup(html)
    par = soup.parsed_html.find('td', attrs={'id':'west1'}).string
    print par
```

But the result is still the same.

Comment: What does "it crashes" mean? Does it print an exception with traceback and then quit? If so, show us the exception and traceback (and, of course, the code that the traceback refers to).

Comment: File "C:\py\projectparse\logparse.py", line 53, in parseo
    par = parsed_html.find('td', attrs={'id':'west1'}).string
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag with `id="west1"` is an `<a>` tag. You are looking for the `<td>` tag that comes after this `<a>` tag:

```
import BeautifulSoup as bs

content = '''<div class="widget_title clearfix">
        <h2>Account Balance</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="widget_body">
        <div class="widget_content">
            <table class="simple">
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="#" id="west1" title="Total earned daily">Daily Earnings</a></td>
                    <td style="text-align: right; width: 125px; color: #119911; font-weight: bold;">
                        150                         
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="#" id="west2" title="Total weekly earnings">Weekly Earnings</a></td>
                    <td style="text-align: right; border-bottom: 1px solid #000; color: #119911; font-weight: bold;">
                        500                     </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="#" id="west3" title="Total Monthly earnings">Monthly Earnings</a></td>
                    <td style="text-align: right; color: #119911; font-weight: bold;">
                        1500                        </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="#" id="west4" title="Total expenses">Total expended</a></td>
                    <td style="text-align: right; border-bottom: 1px solid #000; color: #880000; font-weight: bold;">
                        430                     </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="#" id="west5" title="Total available">Account Balance</a></td>
                    <td style="text-align: right; border-bottom: 3px double #000; color: #119911; font-weight: bold;">
                        840                     </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td style="padding: 5px;">
                        <center>
                            <form id="request_bill" method="POST" action="index.php?page=dashboard">
                                <input type="hidden" name="secret_token" value="" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="request_payout" value="1" />
                                <input type="submit" class="btn blue large" value="Request Payout" />
                            </form>
                        </center>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>'''

def parseo(archivohtml):
    html = archivohtml
    parsed_html = bs.BeautifulSoup(html)
    par = parsed_html.find('a', attrs={'id':'west1'}).findNext('td')        
    print par.string.strip()

parseo(content)
```

yields

```
150
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer!
I've tried your code, but I have a problem with the bs.BeautifulSoup(html) expression...

Where do I declare bs?

My import is from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

Do I have to add bs = BeautifulSoup() at the begining?

I've also seen that BeautifulSoup can be imported as "import BeautifulSoup as bs", but it still doesn't work

I get "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findNext'"

I don't know what I am doing wrong!

Comment: Thank you very much!
Now the code runs, and it does show what it's expected to show, and now I've managed to see what the error was!

The problem was that I was also saving an .html file with all the content, in order to monitorize if all the process was going well, but I wasn't applying BS to the html code itself. I was doing that to the .html code

Now it works perfectly and I can continue working on it!

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from your question if this will be applicable to you, but here's another method:

```
def parseo(archivohtml):
    html = archivohtml
    parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(html)
    for line in parsed_html.stripped_strings:        
        print line.strip()
```

which yields:

```
Account Balance
Daily Earnings
150
Weekly Earnings
500
Monthly Earnings
1500
Total expended
430
Account Balance
840
```

And if you wanted the data in a list:

`data = [line.strip() for line in parsed_html.stripped_strings]`

```
[u'Account Balance', u'Daily Earnings', u'150', u'Weekly Earnings', u'500', u'Monthly Earnings', u'1500', u'Total expended', u'430', u'Account Balance', u'840']
```

Comment: Thank you so much to you too!
Now the code is working, this way to store information and style it is long way better than the one I was using!